# C++ How to copy a part of vector into array?

Tags: c++, copy, stdvector, stdarray, stdcopy

I was making a copy from a large dynamic array to a small fixed size array.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dumpVec.size() - 16; i++)
{
    copy(dumpArr + i, dumpArr + i + 16, temp); // to copy 16 bytes from dynamic array
}
```

But I should use a vector instead of dynamic array. How to copy 16 bytes from vector into array?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dumpVec.size() - 16; i++)
{
    array<byte, 16> temp;
    // place to copy each 16 bytes from dumpVec(byte vector) into temp(byte array)
}
```

Comment: @Yksisarvinen it's done

Comment: Btw, do you make changes to the values in `temp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
copy(dumpArr + i, dumpArr + i + 16, temp); // to copy 16 bytes from dynamic array
```

can be written as

```
copy(&dumpArr[i], &dumpArr[i + 16], &temp[0]); // to copy 16 bytes from dynamic array
```

and now the same code works for `vector` and `array` too.

You can also use

```
copy_n(&dumpArr[i], 16, &temp[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n):

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec(/* large number */);
std::array<int, 16> temp;
std::copy_n(std::begin(vec), 16, std::begin(temp));
```

If you don't want to copy the first 16 elements, just step it forward:

```cpp
std::copy_n(std::next(std::begin(vec), step), 16, std::begin(temp));
```